# Не могу обработать массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы, api, telegram, бот

Есть функция

```
    function getFile($file_id) {
  $file_path_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/getFile?file_id=' . $file_id), TRUE);
    $file_path = $file_path_array['result']['file_path'];
    $file_path_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot00037100:XXXkXU9L8DXXXXXUSY0R36XXCQ9d3XXXX/'.$file_path;
    return $file_path_url;
}
```

Обрабатывает она массив формата

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"file_id":"XXXXqcxGwyaYxXXXXXVvITMmrQ4ABOlO5XXX1KQBAXXX","file_size":47984,"file_path":"photos/file_0.jpg"}}
```

Почему то она может переварить значения file_id и file_size но вот нужное file_path выводить категорически отказывается

Comment: var_dump(getFile($file_id));

что возвращает?

Comment: Так ты же не выполняешь запрос `$file_path_url`, ты его просто выводишь где `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Я делаю так $url = getFile('ТУТ ID');. Я пробовал за место выборки file_path брать file_size или file_id, они отображаются, а вот file_path нет, что мешает?